# Popup Dialogue relative to another button

Tags: android, popup

I am new to android and i want to fix a pop up dialogue box relative to another button. I am inflating the popup window using code. How can i get current position of the button so that i can use these values for inflating the pop up window.

Comment: Please post your code. It will be much easier to help. Changing the origin of a `Dialog` is somewhat difficult - but if you are using standard `View` or `Fragment` popups, it is fairly straight-forward. Which are you using?

Comment: Hi Phil,
Thanks for the response. I am using Standard View pop up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the code I use to get the current x/y coordinate of any `View` Object:

```
/**
 * @return the absolute x and y coordinates of the given view
 */
public Point currentPosition(View view)
{
    int[] loc = new int[2];
    view.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
    return new Point(loc[0], loc[1]);
}
```